# Passing methods as props from embeded component to be called by parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building my first React app and am seemingly way over my head. Anyway, I'm trying to take a component like this:

```
export default class Timer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { clock: 0, time: '' }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.play()
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.pause()
  }

  pause() {
    if (interval) {
      clearInterval(interval)
      interval = null
    }
  }
render() {

    return (
      <div className="react-timer" pause={this.pause.bind(this)}>
        <h3 className="seconds"> {this.state.time} {this.props.prefix}</h3>
        <br />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Timer.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.object
}
```

and access it's state and pause functions in another component that is it's parent because the timer is embedded in the other component.

Other component:

```
class Level1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {x: 0, y: 0};
}


render () {
     ...
      return (
      <div>
      <div ref="elem" onMouseMove={this._onMouseMove.bind(this)} id="gameBoard">
        <img id="waldo1" src={require('../images/waldo1(1).jpg')} alt="waldo"/>
      <h2> {x} , {y}</h2>
      </div>

      <button onClick={this.refs.mytimer.pause()}>Pause</button>

      <Timer ref="mytimer" options={OPTIONS}/> <-- Here Timer

      </div>
        ) // return
      } // render
    } //component
```

For example, I'm going to write a function like this:

```
  var isWaldoFound = function (x , y ) {

    if (true) {
    Timer.pause()
    hashHistory.push({ '/result' + this.Timer.state})
    } else {
     ..Whatever.. 
    }
}
```

I've tried using refs and props but when I log anything it's undefined. When I log timer it shows me the Timer but when I log Timer.pause or Timer.pause() it says it is undefined.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is all about your UI being a function of your state; i.e., React is all about state.  So, instead of doing things imperatively, you change your state and the components "react" to the change in state.

You might want to read:
https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html
and
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

In your case, you might pass the "current state" as a prop to the Timer, and then in componentWillRecieveProps() in the Timer, check the new "current state" against the current one, and if there's a change in state, then have the timer transition itself to the new "current state", rather than trying to imperatively tell the timer to transition to a new state.

So, what you're trying to do is not really the "React" way, but you should still be able to make it work...

First, I'd recommend using a callback ref instead of a string ref, and ideally the callback is a class method on the outer component instead of a fat-arrow function so that a new function isn't generated with each render.  Use the ref to capture the Timer instance on first render, store that instance as an instance variable of your Level1 component, and then use the instance later when the pause button is clicked.

Something like this maybe (untested of course):

```
class Level1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.captureTimer.bind(this)
  this.onPauseTimerButtonClicked.bind(this)

  this.state = {x: 0, y: 0};
}

captureTimer(ref) {
    this.timer = ref
}

onPauseTimerButtonClicked() {
    this.timer.pause()
}

render () {
     ...
      return (
      <div>
      <div ref="elem" onMouseMove={this._onMouseMove.bind(this)} id="gameBoard">
        <img id="waldo1" src={require('../images/waldo1(1).jpg')} alt="waldo"/>
      <h2> {x} , {y}</h2>
      </div>

      <button onClick={this.onPauseTimerButtonClicked}>Pause</button>

      <Timer ref={timer => this.captureTimer(timer)} options={OPTIONS}/> <-- Here Timer

      </div>
        ) // return
      } // render
    } //component
```

Comment: Thank you domehead for your input. You spent some time on this... Unfortunately in `onPauseTimerButtonClicked() {
    this.timer.pause()
}` , `this.timer.pause()` is returning `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timer' of null`

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is probably because the `pause` function is not bound to the class.

Try binding it in the constructor of your component:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { clock: 0, time: '' }
  this.pause = this.pause.bind(this);
}
```

Try this pen: https://codepen.io/CarlosEME/pen/xgmYXZ

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `isWaldoFound` is a method of `Level1`.. If so , replace :

```
Timer.pause()
```

By :

```
this.refs.mytimer.pause();
```

Comment: this.refs.mytimer and this.refs.mytimer.pause() are undefined. Do I have to bind refs?